# iOS UIViewcontroller remains visible

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have an app that segues between different viewcontrollers. Recently, I noticed the following issues:

In Xcode 6.4, running in the debugger on a device (not a simulator), clicking stop does not close the first UIViewcontroller, even when the app exits.

Launching a built copy of the app on a device generates multiple identical views on the device. This is only noticeable if you double click the home button to see which apps are running.

I didn't think either of these were possible. How can you check to block multiple launches of the app and make sure all views/view controllers close on exiting?

Comment: The terminology here is confusing and seems to use "view controller" interchangeably with "application instance". Can you clarify what you are seeing and what you believe that means is happening on your device?

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity. The simplest description is that I am seeing a view generated by my app on my iphone at times that I thought this could not happen.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity. The simplest description is that I am seeing a view generated by my app on my iphone at times that I thought this could not happen. The first is when running from Xcode with the device connected. After clicking the stop button in Xcode, the app appears to stop normally, but there is still the view from the app on the iphone until you double click the home button on the phone and drag the view off screen to kill the app. I thought killing the app from Xcode should shut it down completely and leave no trace displayed on an ios device.